# Filter data using params in ember

Tags: ember.js

I'm developing search feature in my app. What I'm trying to do is to filter a car by brand. I have the following in my route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        filterCars(car){
            this.transitionTo('cars',{ queryParams: {brand: car}});
        }
    },
  queryParams: {
    brand: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
  },
    model(params) {
        if(params['marca'] != null){
            this.get('store').query('car', { filter: { brand: params['marca'] } }).then(function(cars) {
              return cars;
            });
        } else {
            return this.get('store').findAll('car');
        }
    }
});
```

When I get the brand from params, I filter only the cars with that given brand. I thought it would work, but it's not working. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: what is `params['marca']`? shouldn't it be `params['brand']`?

Comment: Yes. it's params['brand']. But it's not the problem. It's the brand I'm sending as a get parameter.

Comment: Then this code is correct and should work. Maybe you can give more infos about whats not working? Do you get an error? whats happening? have you tried to reproduce in an `ember-twiddle`? what requests are sent to your server, and are your server responses correct?

Comment: no errors, but it seems the screen is not being updated with the filtered cars.

Answer (score 0):

What is the symptom of your problem?

I notice that your `model` hook has an if statement with two branches, but only one of them (the else branch) results in the function returning a value. The `if` branch resolves a promise, but does nothing with it.

Also: is the code you show for the cars route? You may be able to simplify this page by just changing the `brand` parameter. I'm not sure you need to transition to the same route at all.

Comment: "return this.get('store').findAll('car');" returns a promise for sure and it works. How would I return a promise in the else block then ?

Comment: You already do. It's the `if` block that doesn't return a promise. It should read: something like `return this.get('store').query('car', { filter: { brand: params['marca'] }});`

Comment: it's still returning all the cars instead of just the one I'm searching..

Comment: There are a few things that could cause this. The first thing I would try: open the network inspector and look at the URL being sent to the server. Is it sending the request you expect it to? If so, does the server send back the data you expect?

Answer (score 0):

**Use where clause in filter**

```
    import Ember from 'ember';
    export default Ember.Route.extend({
        actions: {
            filterCars(car){
                this.transitionTo('cars',{ queryParams: {brand: car}});
            }
        },
        queryParams:{
            brand:{
                refreshModel: true
            }
        },
        model(params) {
            if(params['marca'] != null){
                this.get('store').query('car', { filter: { where:{brand: params['marca'] } }}).then(function(cars) {
                  return cars;
                });
            } else {
                return this.get('store').findAll('car');
            }
        }
    });
```